# What is an efficient way of grouping and forming a sorted list of string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can you please advise me on an efficient way of grouping columns and create a list sorted list of string (order by longest string)? An tiny example

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Dept": ["1050", "1051", "1051", "1050"],
    "ProviderId": ["P1", "P2", "P2", "P1"],
    "Block": ["Exam", "Visit", "Away", "Result"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and we have

```
   Dept ProviderId   Block
0  1050         P1   Exam
1  1051         P2   Visit
2  1051         P2   Away
3  1050         P1   Result
```

I hope to have the following

```
   Dept ProviderId   Block
0  1050         P1   Return,Exam
1  1051         P2   Visit,Away
```

`Return` is before `Exam` because `Return` is longer.
same for `Visit` before `Away`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first change order of rows by length of strings by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions, pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for joined values:

```
df1 = (df.iloc[(-df['Block'].str.len()).argsort()]
         .groupby(['Dept','ProviderId'])['Block']
         .agg(','.join)
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   Dept ProviderId        Block
0  1050         P1  Result,Exam
1  1051         P2   Visit,Away
```

Another idea is sorting in lambda function by `sorted` with `key=len`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Dept','ProviderId'])['Block']
        .agg(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x, key=len, reverse=True)))
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
   Dept ProviderId        Block
0  1050         P1  Result,Exam
1  1051         P2   Visit,Away
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can first
  [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
  your dataframe based on `length` of `Block` column using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).
- Then you can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and join the result using [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Code:

```
df.reindex(df['Block'].str.len().sort_values(ascending=False).index)\ 
.groupby(['Dept', 'ProviderId'])['Block']\ 
.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Dept ProviderId        Block
0  1050         P1  Result,Exam
1  1051         P2   Visit,Away
```